# Saving firefox session with selenium (cookies)

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, cookies, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to save cookies from a firefox session driven by selenium in c#. I know i can do it by serializing each cookie for each website and then adding those cookies back on the site, but that's not really the best solution because: 
1. I can't set cookies before joining a site, so i need first visit the site then add cookies, but the site already sets cookies on visit so i need to delete them and set mine which might cause problems with the site. I would rather just let firefox and site handle cookies.
2. I need to worry about expired cookies too
I already tried to copy the temp. firefox profile that selenium creates. But that doesn't seem to have any cookies stored, also loading that profile back doesn't work i get error:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'Failed to set preferences: Unable to read profile preferences file'
```

But that's not the only issue, i don't see any cookie file in the folder i copied, there's only extensions folder and user.js file which has some preferences. Here's the code i used:

```
        internal static void TestCookies()
    {
        //initialize driver and profile
        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
        profile.DeleteAfterUse = false;
        //set a cookie
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://winware.org/en/cookie-permanent.php");
        driver.FindElementByXPath("html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/input").SendKeys("TestValue1");
        driver.FindElementByXPath("html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]/button").Click();
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Console.WriteLine(driver.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies.Count);
        profile.SetPreference("accessibility.typeaheadfind.flashBar", false);
        profile.WriteToDisk();
        Console.WriteLine(profile.ProfileDirectory);
        //move the temp directory to a different location
        Directory.Move(profile.ProfileDirectory, @"C:\Data\FirefoxProfiles\customprofile\");
        driver.Close();

        //test if cookie is still there
        profile = new FirefoxProfile(@"C:\Data\FirefoxProfiles\customprofile\"); //crashes here OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'Failed to set preferences: Unable to read profile preferences file'
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://winware.org/en/cookie-permanent.php");
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Console.WriteLine(driver.Manage().Cookies.GetCookieNamed("PermanentCookie").Value);

    }
```

Does anyone know how to do this without manually managing cookies?

Comment: Why don't you re-use the profile next time?

Comment: I tried , but it doesn't work, i described the problem. When i try to re use the profile it crashes with the error. Also i checked that profile folder and it seems like there are no cookies stored there.

Comment: That is because of because of webdriver related stuff that gets added. Can you use Chrome instead ? That would work in this case

Comment: Ok, I will try with chrome but i would still like a solution for firefox, if there are none i will go with chrome , if chrome works.

Comment: Firefox will require lot of work to get working and then again it may work and break in next version. So I would suggest you work with chrome

Comment: Chrome works, i will switch to chrome, but i will leave this question open i case someone has a solution for firefox.